# Typescript get typeof interface or type's subfield

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given an interface or type declared below,

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: {
    a: number
    b: string
  }
}

type Foo = {
  bar: {
    a: number
    b: string
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the type definitions for "baz". This is so that we can do something like

```js
const v: keyof Foo.bar = "a";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can like that

```
const invalid: Foo["bar"] = "a"; // Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: string; }'.(2322)
const valid: Foo["bar"] = { a: 1, b:'a' };
```

It works with `type` and `interface`. Here's a working [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=5&pln=8&pc=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXDvgcnOSAK4C2h0lBh5AzmFKAOaUBfXENwB6UcjABPAA4oMWALwVxVYmRUSq1Wo2ZQxWtZ259DVIapEJ0ILslAA3OABtgAE3IKA2gCJ1vgC6yMq+cL4A3Lg2dmDIzm6eaJh+AcHK2DrIAIwANESkAORwhcgCEUA)